# Rendering height after changing fontsize is not correct

Tags: css, font-size, ckeditor4.x

As I am working on a project where space between the line matters and should change according to the size of the font, I am unable to resolve the height issue of a paragraph. My css for the document is as follows:

```
body {
  background: transparent;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

p {
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
}
```

As I change the font size of some paragraph to the size lower than 14px, the height of the paragraph remains same even if the font size is changed and the space taken by paragraph remains same whereas expected behaviour is the height of the space taken by the text should be decreased. Please find the attachment for reference.

[image]

Comment: Improve formatting of your post and embed images, please [edit].

Comment: Do you need `line-height`? If so, are you adjusting that with the `font-size`?

Comment: @hc_dev Sorry but I don't have enough reputation to post the embed images.
 Bruno: I need line height to keep the lines very close to each other. Although line height is not issue here.

Comment: I have merged the image so that it is easier to review the issue.

Comment: @ArunRajthala I mentioned `line-height` because that will also affect the height of your paragrpah. If you change `font-size` but keep the same `line-height`, you may have an unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro I think line-height:1 means it should scale according to the font size.

Comment: @ArunRajthala I think you are right, but I would play with that number in the browser inspect, just to make sure it's not being an issue. Good luck :)

Comment: font-size: 14px !important;

Comment: @LDS, I want the space(height) occupied by the line to be decreased when the font size is changed to 8px. Why would you put important on font size?

Comment: Sorry I thing the problem of font . It may take the margin or padding ,if so for div style change the margin or padding and put important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a feature to be developed by CKEDITOR team according to [github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor4/issues/3328](http://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor4/issues/3328). Maybe we will get it some day but workaround for this would be setting smallest font-size as default size and then the space changes according to the font size. eg. .cke_editable {font-size: 8px;line-height: 1;}